# Is there a way to select changes at a patch level in git's cherry-pick?

Tags: git, cherry-pick

I would like to be able to select which changes to include in the `cherry-pick` at a patch-level much like the `-p` option when adding changes to commit?

Comment: You could use the `--no-commit` option and then discard what you don't want.

Comment: Yes. First you `git cherry-pick -n <commit>`, then you can `git reset -p` and select every chunk you want to unstage before finally committing.

Answer (score 0):

You could use git show instead of git cherry-pick command:

```
git show <commit_id> -- <file_path> | git apply
```

Then, commit your changes.